# register postgres with eureka with out docker image

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

How to register a database server like a "PostgreSQL" or any other sql database with eureka server and use it in spring boot micro service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to register `Postgres`, `Elastic Search`, etc. or in-house non-`JVM` services you would have to implement the `Sidecar` pattern, a companion application to the main services that serves has a mediator between the main service and `Eureka`, for instance.

To do so using `Docker` it's a little bit tricky because it's a suggested practice for a `Docker` container to run just one process but using a `Sidecar` along with the main service you would have to either run two process or make changes / provide implementation in the `Sidecar` application to support the `Sidecar` and `Postgres` to run in different `Docker` containers.

I recently blogged about this exact topic at [Microservices Sidecar pattern implementation using Postgres, Spring Cloud Netflix and Docker](http://tech.asimio.net/2018/02/20/Microservices-Sidecar-pattern-implementation-using-Postgres-Spring-Cloud-Netflix-and-Docker.html).

I decided to run both, the `Sidecar` app and `Postgres` in the same container but I might follow up on this in the future.

Comment: Thanks ootero again. Just by following your guidence i made an example and kept in below location "https://github.com/chaitanyakakarala/springbootrestapi"

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a simple microservice, which has access to the database and expose endpoints to the repositories.

> For services that are non-Java based, you have a choice of implementing the client part of eureka in the language of the service [[1]](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-at-a-glance#non-java-services-and-clients)

You cannot register a PostgresSQL Database as a service to Eureka directly.

EDIT: Since every microservice serves a specific concern, it should has its own data store. If you centralize the data store, it becomes your bottleneck and you limit the scalability of the microservices using the data store.

Comment: But, such a kind of feasibility is there in has-hi corp consul application. So should i be using hostname / ip and port number for connecting to database server right ? Unfortunately using consul is not a choice for me. I want to get rid of using ip and port number for url in datasource properties.

Comment: You have to connect to database at least at one point and this is within it's own microservice which registers his service to eureka. All other microservices use the new microservice to get access to the database.